# Yii2 показать страницу ошибки

Tags: php, yii2, исключения

В контроллере, в методе `beforeAction` делаю некую проверку и если она не проходит, надо выкинуть ошибку. Делаю так

```
throw new ForbiddenHttpException('У вас нету прав для просмотра этого раздела');
```

Все срабатывает, получаю это сообщение. Но мне надо что бы не просто исключение показывалось, а показывалась страничка с ошибкой.

Помогите, что то не могу нагуглить и понять как сделать

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то так:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
   if(...) {
       echo $this->render('error');
       return false; //Это для того, чтобы устранить рендер запрошенного action
   }

   return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```